# How to query the dbContext to find which entities have parent-child relationships between them?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using EF 6.0 in asp.net. I have a complex dbContext which has tens of entities. I would like to know which entities have parent-child relationships between them?

I started with using this:

```
var test = dbContext.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(~EntityState.Modified).Where(e => e.IsRelationship)
                .Select(e => e.Entity);
```

However I received an exception 'Objects in a detached state do not exist in the ObjectStateManager'. 
Are there other ways to interrogate the dbContext?
Also when checking the dbContext in the debugger, which property in an entity indicates it has children and where they are located?

Comment: Well, you can get the collection navigation properties of an entity, but may I ask why you want this?